# LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error 10810 in iTerm2 running tmux on Yosemite

Tags: macos, iterm, zsh, tmux

```
[~%]open ~/Pictures/upload.png
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/bryanhunt/Pictures/upload.png.
```

Before this update I used to be able to open images, PDFs, etc. from the command line.

Now I have to open the directory, and click on the file to open it, which is a waste of my finger strength.

Anyone know how to make it work again?

Comment: What update are you referring to? Yosemite? iTerm2? tmux?

Comment: Here is a similar question on SuperUser. Perhaps one of these answers would work for you. http://superuser.com/questions/834525/unable-to-launch-application-in-tmux

Comment: That looks like the best bet, looks like it is only a problem for tmux users.

Comment: Yeah it works, ugly hack going on there :)

Answer (score 4):

The fix.

Install homebrew.

Install reattach-to-user-namespace:

```
 brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

Then create an alias which your shell can use:

```
 alias open='reattach-to-user-namespace open'
```

Comment: Why does this work? and brew is not part of OS X

Comment: @Mark You sohuld read about *Bootstrap Namespaces* here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SECTION9 . There's common problem for devs when they want to launch GUI app from daemon for example. That's why when running `tmux` You have to attach to *User* namespace in order to be able to "talk" to proper launchd.